# Angular-Routing not working in Cloud, but on localhost

Tags: html, css, angular, nginx, angular-routing

I set up an angular website with a couple of components. When using `ng serve` and browsing on localhost, the routing is working just fine. But when deployed on cloud, only the starting page is working. Routing to any other component is not working and I receive the error:
`404 Not Found` nginx/1.16.0.

I tried using the approaches such as `pathMatch: 'full'` and creating a Staticfile with pushstate enabled.

I am also using `<base href="/">`.

app-routing-module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: IndexComponent, pathMatch : 'full'},
  { path: 'login', component: StartComponent, pathMatch : 'full'},
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'forgot', component: ServiceComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'impressum', component: ImpComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routingComponents = [IndexComponent, StartComponent]
```

nginx config:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  localhost;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

I can not see why there is a difference in the localhost and the server-sided routing and how to fix it.

Comment: make sure you have set the correct `<base href="/">` for your app

Comment: i did that already

Comment: i had similar problem with apache server , solved it following way. may be this helps : http://joeljoseph.net/angular-6-deploy-on-apache-server-by-solving-404-not-found-error-on-page-refresh/

Comment: You need to set your server up to redirect non-asset requests to your app's `index.html`.  Currently, it's trying to load files at the URLs you request as opposed to allowing Angular to handle the routing.

Comment: thanks for your reply. could you explain that in detail, please?

Comment: @Steve everything is detailed here https://angular.io/guide/deployment

Answer (score 2):

> providers: [ {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy} ]

in app.module.ts

The Angular location strategies are here: https://angular.io/api/common/LocationStrategy this is the Hash Strategy. As @WillAlexander stated the server is trying to handle the routing and is trying to locate files in the file structure based on the route instead of letting Angular handle the routing. This is a common problem for Angular beginners and the other strategies can be found on the link I provided as well as here: https://angular.io/guide/deployment. Hope it helps.

Comment: That fixed my project but broke my self esteem /s